# Low rank matrix manifold intersects subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

Let $M_r\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the manifold of rank $r$ matrices. Let $\mathbb{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a subspace of dimension $m$. Let $X\in M_r\cap\mathbb{V}$ be a given matrix and we denote the tangent space at $X$ with respect to the manifold by $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{T}_{X}M_r$.

So my question is: is $M_r\cap\mathbb{V}$ still a manifold?

And if the answer was yes, what can we say about the relation between the dimension of $M_r\cap\mathbb{V}$ and dimension of $\mathbb{V}\cap\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: You should read about "transversality". In general, there is no reason that the intersection will be a manifold but if the intersection is transversal, it will be and the dimension of $M_r \cap \mathbb{V}$ will be the same as the dimension of $\mathbb{T} \cap \mathbb{V}$ (which will also be the tangent space to the intersection at $X$).

Comment: @levap Thanks a lot! I will check it.